# How might an Ubuntu 18.04 system that has somehow had Python 2 removed be recovered?

Tags: python, dpkg

A friend tried to help another friend on his Ubuntu 18.04 installation and that somehow involved (as far as I can figure) removing Python 2. This seems to have resulted in poor `apt`, `apt-get` and `dpkg -i` being broken. To try to fix things, I was thinking initially that we could manually download the Python 2 DEB package (https://packages.ubuntu.com/bionic/amd64/python2.7/download) but then we, of course, ran into the problem of getting `dpkg -i` to run (`py_compile.py` syntax errors). Like, `apt` throws up errors like the following:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/usr/bin/pycompile", line 35, in <module>
from debpython.version import SUPPORTED, debsorted, vrepr, \
File "/usr/share/python/debpython/version.py", line 24, in <module>
from ConfigParser import SafeConfigParser
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'ConfigParser'
```

That tells me that this poor, confused system is trying its best to run Python 3 on some Python 2 code that is a part of `apt`, `dpkg` and the whole shebang.

So now I'm thinking that we could create a virtual environment with its own wee Python 2 executable installed and tell the system to use that (by simlinking `/usr/bin/python` to the virtual environment Python executable) in order to run `dpkg -i` on the proper Python 2 package we have downloaded here.

Would this screw things up more or is this a plausible thing to try?

---

EDIT: Terminal out put of `ll /usr/bin/python*`:

```
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 9 Apr 16 15:31 /usr/bin/python -> python2.7*
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 9 Apr 16 15:31 /usr/bin/python2 -> python2.7*
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 4576440 Sep 21 14:09 /usr/bin/python2.7*
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 33 Apr 15 22:51 /usr/bin/python2.7-config -> x86_64-linux-gnu-python2.7-config*
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 9 Jun 21 22:52 /usr/bin/python3 -> python3.6*
-rwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4567672 Sep 12 19:26 /usr/bin/python3.6*
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 33 Sep 12 19:26 /usr/bin/python3.6-config -> x86_64-linux-gnu-python3.6-config*
-rwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4567672 Sep 12 19:26 /usr/bin/python3.6m*
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 34 Sep 12 19:26 /usr/bin/python3.6m-config -> x86_64-linux-gnu-python3.6m-config*
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 16 Jun 21 22:52 /usr/bin/python3-config -> python3.6-config*
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 10 Jun 21 22:52 /usr/bin/python3m -> python3.6m*
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 17 Jun 21 22:52 /usr/bin/python3m-config -> python3.6m-config*
```

It should be noted that when any of the commands `python`, `python2` and `python2.7` are run, they all launch Python 3.6.

Comment: Can you copy this from system and post above? `ll /usr/bin/python*
` It should show links, but my system only installed 2.7 when I added a couple of apps that have not yet been converted to python3.  I might just chroot into system from an 18.04 live installer and reinstall python3.

Comment: @oldfred Hey there, thanks for the suggestion. I've added an edit there with the output. Note that all the usual commands that would launch Python 2 instead launch Python 3!

Comment: As a rule of thumb, right now as we are on the conversion from 2.7 to 3.x is: You can always install other python versions as single standing versions but you should, when in doubt never remove a python version, just live with the small disk space used.

Comment: @Videonauth Haha, yes *I* know this but the person working on my friend's machine did not. I'm not trying to come up with some mad but workable way to fix the thing.

Comment: @BlandCorporation Well best course of action I see here is use a live boot USB and chroot into that system for reinstalling python as olfred pointed out already.

Comment: @Videonauth Thanks, I may well give that a go, but would you have *any* ideas about how to force the system to use the version of Python 2 that *I* have installed for all of its system things like `apt` and `dpkg`? They all are defaulting to some Python 3 version and I really want this not to happen because it breaks everything.

Comment: Hard to tell, if you're using the normal python version from the repository they can finely coexist on 18.04, whats baffling me is that dpkg throws you errors, it should be meanwhile depend on python 3.x

Comment: You show python is linked to python2.7, and all the rest of the entries are identical to mine which is default configuration. Or do not know where you are getting python3 when launching python2. My other default install of Bionic has no python2. So every default app in Ubuntu should be using python3.

Comment: @Videonauth Whelp when `dpkg` or `apt` run they end up with problems like `No module named 'ConfigParser'`, which tells me that the system is trying to run Python 3 on some Python 2 code that is used by `apt`, `dpkg` and whatnot. AFAICS this person removed Python 2 from the machine and I'm trying to tell the system to use (temporarily) a version of Python that is installed manually (in a wee Miniconda environment). Hopefully this gets `apt` and `dpkg` working such that they can install Python 2 things on the system again.

Comment: @oldfred I'm seeing things like `No module named 'ConfigParser'` when I try to run `apt`, for example, which tells me (unless I'm wrong) that the system is trying to run Python 3 on some Python 2 code, and that Python 2 code is being used by `apt` and `dpkg`. I'm trying to get the system to use my manual installation of Python 2 so that it can run `apt` and what not to dig this machine out of its madness. :)

Comment: `dpkg` is written in C, not Python, and does not depend upon Python. Any Python-related errors when using `dpkg` should be related to setup of that particular Python package, not a `dpkg` fault - read the error messages very carefully. To restore Py2, you must reinstall the `python2.7-minimal` package, and it's dependencies in the correct order, using `dpkg`. It's not hard (done it), but it can be a bit tedious. All other Py2-related packages depend upon `-minimal`-provided features like ConfigParser().

Answer (score 0):

You might be able to re-install all packages via:

```
sudo apt install --reinstall ubuntu-desktop
```

Comment: Hey, thanks for the suggestion. Unfortunately `apt` breaks if Python 2 isn't there. Catch-22! So the current plan is to try to get the system to use a manually-installed Python 2 that is in Miniconda. But we can't figure how to get the system to use this Python 2 executable so that `apt` can then work and be used to reinstall a proper system version of Python 2!

Comment: You might want to try `dpkg-reconfigure python2.7` first. Also check `which python` to see which python is being executed. Finally you might also want to try `update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/python python /usr/bin/python2.7 1`